# How do you set a standard display typeface and font size in Process Studio?

Tags: blueprism

Is there a way to set a standard or default type face/font size for all newly added stages to a BluePrism instance's Process Studio? I have only been able to edit this after each stage is added. This would help readability on process maps that sprawl too much for zooming alone.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a way to do that, so usually, I just ctrl+a and set it afterwards.